# How to use nonce with Google in app billing api V3

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I am trying to implement in app purchase in my android application. I am using In app billing API v3 for implementing IAP (in app purchase). For reference I am following Google provided trivialdrive sample. In `launchPurchaseFlow` method

```
public void launchPurchaseFlow(Activity act, String sku, String itemType, int requestCode,
                        OnIabPurchaseFinishedListener listener, String extraData) {
        checkSetupDone("launchPurchaseFlow");
        flagStartAsync("launchPurchaseFlow");
        IabResult result;

        if (itemType.equals(ITEM_TYPE_SUBS) && !mSubscriptionsSupported) {
            IabResult r = new IabResult(IABHELPER_SUBSCRIPTIONS_NOT_AVAILABLE, 
                    "Subscriptions are not available.");
            if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(r, null);
            return;
        }

        try {
            logDebug("Constructing buy intent for " + sku + ", item type: " + itemType);
            Bundle buyIntentBundle = mService.getBuyIntent(3, mContext.getPackageName(), sku, itemType, extraData);
            int response = getResponseCodeFromBundle(buyIntentBundle);
            if (response != BILLING_RESPONSE_RESULT_OK) {
                logError("Unable to buy item, Error response: " + getResponseDesc(response));

                result = new IabResult(response, "Unable to buy item");
                if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
                return;
            }

            PendingIntent pendingIntent = buyIntentBundle.getParcelable(RESPONSE_BUY_INTENT);
            logDebug("Launching buy intent for " + sku + ". Request code: " + requestCode);
            mRequestCode = requestCode;
            mPurchaseListener = listener;
            mPurchasingItemType = itemType;
            act.startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
                                           requestCode, new Intent(),
                                           Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
                                           Integer.valueOf(0));
        }
        catch (SendIntentException e) {
            logError("SendIntentException while launching purchase flow for sku " + sku);
            e.printStackTrace();

            result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_SEND_INTENT_FAILED, "Failed to send intent.");
            if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
        }
        catch (RemoteException e) {
            logError("RemoteException while launching purchase flow for sku " + sku);
            e.printStackTrace();

            result = new IabResult(IABHELPER_REMOTE_EXCEPTION, "Remote exception while starting purchase flow");
            if (listener != null) listener.onIabPurchaseFinished(result, null);
        }
    }
```

In the above code `getBuyIntent` does not expect `nonce`, we have extradata in which we pass developerpayload (specific to each purchase item).
Here I am not able to figure out how to pass nonce as it was passed in API V2 and received as response on successful purchase. Is there no need of `nonce` in V3?

Thanks

Comment: nonce is required in V3 also. I will check api and update here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using IAB API v3, simply use the original JSON response you receive from Google Play and perform an OpenSSL verification on it, using the signature and public RSA.

It's best that you perform this check through your own API, as bundling the public RSA key inside your application is unsafe. [Here's a PHP sample for this OpenSSL verification.](https://github.com/mgoldsborough/google-play-in-app-billing-verification/blob/master/library/GooglePlay/InAppBilling/GooglePlayResponseValidator.php)

As that sample illustrates, it simply takes the parameters from the request: the response data and the signature and verifies it using the public key.

You only need to tamper with the original JSON data inside your app and on your API for purposes related to figuring out what the user bought, **not** for verifying the validity of the purchase itself.

So in short: don't worry about the nonce. IAB API v3 dropped it and you shouldn't concern yourself with its absence.

Comment: Is there a way to handle replay attacks? Looking at http://code.google.com/p/marketbilling/issues/detail?id=127 it doesn't look like there's anything stopping a user from simply recording the JSON and re-transmitting it from a different device. Looking at the V2 docs a genuine nonce used to be present to ensure that the purchase data was actually generated in real time on the device but that was apparently removed. Is there an alternate way to achieve the same goal (preventing replay attacks)?

Comment: @Femi The request should be executed through your app's IAP logic. You can generate a nonce before the Google Play purchase, and send it with the purchase confirmation to your API's receipt check end-point. An attacker would both have to recompile the app and trap all requests; surely that would be too much work for the average pirater.

Answer (score 0):

APIv3 returns orderId, which can be used as nonce to avoid replay attacks.